# image watermarking in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

every time i water mark an image it changes the background to black,jst wnt to know if this is a bug , if no what can be done to change it

Comment: what code are you using?

Comment: @user644384 Please, post a little source code to get a better view. More info about Image Watermarking in CI in this link http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the user_guide carefully for the image library, actually in the watermark section, this problem was going with me and i solved it from the user_guide .. your watermark image should has at least one transparent point, so you can assign it as the color which you need it to be transparent after posting the watermark, checkout this example:

```
$image_cfg = array();
$image_cfg['image_library'] = 'GD2';
$image_cfg['source_image'] = '--HERE THE PATH TO IMAGE THAT WILL TAKE WATERMARK--';
$image_cfg['wm_overlay_path'] = '--HERE THE PATH TO THE WATERMARK IMAGE ITSELF--';
$image_cfg['new_image'] = '--HERE THE PATH TO SAVE THE NEW IMAGE AFTER WATERMARK--';
$image_cfg['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
$image_cfg['wm_opacity'] = '99';
$image_cfg['wm_x_transp'] = 200;
$image_cfg['wm_y_transp'] = 200;
$image_cfg['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'top';
$image_cfg['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'left';
$image_cfg['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
$this->image_lib->initialize($image_cfg);
$this->image_lib->watermark();
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

note the part of wm_x_transp and wm_y_transp ... those two parts assign the x and y of pixel to make its color transparent in the final result, it's by default 4,4 and i think that this pixel in your case isn't transparent, try this answer and it will work